# How do you move a set of links from current to global navigation en masse?

Tags: navigation

I accidentally added all my global navigation (including several subsites inside folders) into the Current Navigation section in the Navigation settings.  I'm so used to working with actual files when I build websites and I would normally just cut and paste the block of link code and be done in 2 minutes.  But it's looking like I'm going to have to manually re-enter all those links individually because I don't know how to access that code in the actual SharePoint files and since I assume they are actually in the content database.  Please tell me there is a way to move all those links en masse up to the global section?

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, you can access the navigation nodes, including Global and Quick Launch. You won't be able to 'move' the navigation nodes, but you can do a loop to read the nodes from Quick Launch and create those nodes to Global then delete the nodes from Quick Launch.

This article should help you get started: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.nz/2015/02/working-with-quick-launch-from.html

Comment: What a great idea!  I will give this a shot!  I'm not too experienced writing scripts but I bet this one might be simple enough.  And I like a challenge and to learn new things.  Thank you!